# Xamarin - RaisePropertyChanged does not call setter of custom component's BindableProperty

Tags: xamarin, binding, prism

I've createad a custom component `MyComponent`, which contains one bindable property called `Title`. The goal is, that when `Title` property changes (via binding or setter), the `propertyChanged` callback of `BindableProperty` sets new value to underlying ViewModel (`MyComponentViewModel`), which causes some business logic to update (this works).

This is simplified implementation of `MyComponent.xaml.cs`:

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class MyComponent {

     public MyComponentViewModel ViewModel => BindingContext as MyComponentViewModel;

     public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Title),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyComponent),
        "?",
        BindingMode.Default,
        propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => (b as MyComponent).ViewModel.Title = (string)n
    );
    
    public string Title {
        get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }


    public MyComponent() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
```

The problem is, that the setter of `MyComponent.Title` property is not called when binding value changes (nor the propertyChanged event). When the `Title` is set to hardcoded value, it works fine. Let me demonstrate on a minimal example:

`TestPageViewModel.cs`:

```
  public class TestPageViewModel : Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase {
  
    
     private string _translationTest;
     public string TranslationTest {
        get => _translationTest;
        set {
            _translationTest = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
      } 
    
      public TestPageViewModel() {
        TranslationTest = "SomeRandomText";
      }
  
  }
```

and a page using ViewModel above:

`TestPage.xaml`:

```
  <ContentPage ...>
  
  
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <app:TestPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <StackLayout>
    
        <!-- Binding to label text -- works: outputs `SomeRandomText` -->
        <Label Text="{Binding TranslationTest}"/>
        
        <!-- Binding this same, but to custom component -- does not work: setter not called & changed callback not fired -->
        <app:MyComponent Title="{Binding TranslationTest}"/>

        <!-- Using hardcoded value works, outputs: 'SomeHardcodedValue' -->
        <app:MyComponent Title="SomeHardcodedValue"/>
    
    </StackLayout>
  
  </ContentPage>
```

`MyComponent.xaml`

```
  <ContentView...>
  
  
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <app:MyComponentViewModel/>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>
    
    <Grid>
        <!-- some logic based on values ofapp:MyComponentViewModel -->
    </Grid>
  
  </ContentView>
```

What I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: You're binding the property on the component to a property on the view model of the component and expect it to change *that same property*? The `BindingContext` of `app:MyComponent` is the `app:TestPageViewModel` created above...

Comment: @Haukinger - No, the `BindingContext` of `MyComponent` is `MyComponentViewModel` as the property `MyComponent.ViewModel` states. The value of the ViewModel is set in propertyChanged callback, not bound.

Comment: I'm talking about the code from `Testpage.xaml` you posted - there, the `BindingContext` of `MyComponent` is, obviously, an instance of `TestPageViewModel`, namely the one created in the xaml.

Comment: @Haukinger - This is simply not true. I did set BindingContext of `MyComponent` to instance of `MyComponentViewModel` exactly the same like I did with `TestPage` and `TestPageViewModel`. I set a x:Name for both `app:MyComponent` inside `TestPage` and requested BindingContext property in `OnAppearing` of `TestPage` and they are clearly instances of `MyComponentViewModel`.

Comment: Not in the question you posted yesterday. Anyway, this way of "splitting" between view and view model makes no sense to begin with - the component is never entitled to a specific view model, it is given one by the consumer. And it interacts with it only through bound properties, never directly.

Comment: I did not posted it yesterday because it was not relevant to what I am asking. I am not splitting anything, the MyComponent is supposed to be universal and usable in many different pages, with different ViewModels. The MyComponentViewModel is only for internal use (binding) inside MyComponent view (and in my actual code it's private). The result I want to achieve is reflect changes made to `TestPageViewModel.TranslationTest` to `MyComponent.Title` (which internaly updates it's own, independent ViewModel), but the change of TranslationTest won't trigger the Title property.

Comment: There's no such thing as `it's own, independent ViewModel`

Comment: Okay, thanks for help with "RaisePropertyChanged does not call setter of custom component's BindableProperty"

Comment: `Title="{Binding TranslationTest}"` is relative to `app:MyComponent`'s `BindingContext`, that is, as of now, `app:MyComponentViewModel`.

Comment: @Haukinger - Oh thank you. It turns out that I've been 'overriding' `MyComponent`'s BindingContext with `MyComponentViewModel` and that caused the property not to update because of different context. I resolved it by setting `MyComponentViewModel` as BindingContext of underlying StackLayout inside `MyComponent` and now it works as expected. Thanks for pointing me to right direction.

Comment: That's why most would recommend against that architecture - whatever `MyComponentViewModel.Title` does, it should be done in `MyComponent`.